# Суммирование значений по уникальным ID

Tags: excel

Имеется таблица значений в Excel полученная из таблицы Oracle.
Пример:

```
 +--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
|                  ID                  |                  IDS                 |  USL   |  SUM   |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| FBD9F9D3-36AE-4C28-8AFB-8096F9F461C4 | 8AA4E7C8-0165-4F6C-81B9-31B8F12B69DB |  35656 | 589.50 |
| 6DE76207-AFF4-400E-8DF8-BFD0503AD9A0 | E2DBFB49-8F4E-46C7-91C5-D12D2AA91CFC |  35658 | 650.00 |
| 6DE76207-AFF4-400E-8DF8-BFD0503AD9A0 | E44BCDFB-30C1-46FA-960B-B85F271CB1CF |  35656 | 650.00 |
| 6DE76207-AFF4-400E-8DF8-BFD0503AD9A0 | E44BCDFB-30C1-46ED-960B-B85F271CB1CF | 185245 | 650.00 |
| 4665A34A-550F-4CC6-A3EF-23B2B7863CAA | 1DC72AE5-452C-4D20-A48F-98F320C05D30 |  89556 | 205.20 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
```

Пытаюсь сложить колонку SUM через сводную таблицу по уникальным значениям ID
через вычисляемое поле:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(ACTUAL[SUM]);FILTER(ACTUAL;DISTINCTCOUNT(ACTUAL[ID])))
```

Но к сожалению не получается.

На выходе хотелось бы получить :

Имеется таблица значений в Excel полученная из таблицы Oracle.
Пример:

```
 +--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
|                  ID                  |                  IDS                 |  USL   |  SUM   |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| FBD9F9D3-36AE-4C28-8AFB-8096F9F461C4 | 8AA4E7C8-0165-4F6C-81B9-31B8F12B69DB |  35656 | 589.50 |
| 6DE76207-AFF4-400E-8DF8-BFD0503AD9A0 | E2DBFB49-8F4E-46C7-91C5-D12D2AA91CFC |  35658 | 650.00 |
| 6DE76207-AFF4-400E-8DF8-BFD0503AD9A0 | E44BCDFB-30C1-46FA-960B-B85F271CB1CF |  35656 | 650.00 |
| 6DE76207-AFF4-400E-8DF8-BFD0503AD9A0 | E44BCDFB-30C1-46ED-960B-B85F271CB1CF | 185245 | 650.00 |
| 4665A34A-550F-4CC6-A3EF-23B2B7863CAA | 1DC72AE5-452C-4D20-A48F-98F320C05D30 |  89556 | 205.20 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
```

Пытаюсь сложить колонку SUM через сводную таблицу по уникальным значениям ID
через вычисляемое поле:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(ACTUAL[SUM]);FILTER(ACTUAL;DISTINCTCOUNT(ACTUAL[ID])))
```

Но к сожалению не получается.

На выходе хотелось бы получить что-то похожее на:

```
+--------------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
|                   ID                 | COUNT(IDS) |  SUM   | CALCULATE  |
+--------------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
| FBD9F9D3-36AE-4C28-8AFB-8096F9F461C4 |          1 | 589.50 |    589.50  |
| 6DE76207-AFF4-400E-8DF8-BFD0503AD9A0 |          3 | 650.00 |     650.00 |
| 4665A34A-550F-4CC6-A3EF-23B2B7863CAA |          1 | 205.20 |     205.20 |
+--------------------------------------+------------+--------+------------+
```

Изначальная таблица - это развёрнутый XML со следующей структурой:

```
+-------------+
|   ACTUAL    |
+-------------+
| ├── ID      |
| │   ├── IDS |
| │   └── USL |
| └── SUM     |
+-------------+
```

Comment: А зачем вычисляемое поле? Сводная таблица сама просуммирует значения по одинаковым id. Просто добавьте id как столбцы, а sum как значения(сумма)

Comment: В том то и проблема что в одном столбце суммируются IDS как количество, а в другом суммируется столбец SUM по критерию уникальности ID. Что-то типо (select id, sum(sum) from (select distinct id, sum from ACTUAL))

Comment: Непонятно. Если в приведённом примере в третьей строке изменить сумму с 650.00 на, скажем, 700.00 - как изменится вывод?

Comment: Она не изменится. Это развёрнутый XML в таблице. [ID] родитель [IDS]. Колонка [SUM] находится на уровне родителя. Колонка [USL] на уровне [IDS].

Comment: То есть вам нужна не сумма по столбцу sum - а просто 1 значение? ТО есть на одинаквые ID всегда будут одинаковые суммы?

Comment: Макросом обработать не желаете? Или формулами, если строк не сотни тысяч (сколько?)?

Comment: Данных по count на 54М записей.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял - то зачем использовать доп поля вычисляемые? 
Итого просто создайте на основе ваших данных сводную таблицу:
Строки: ID
Значения: IDS (кол-во) и SUM (макс/среднее - так как у вас четко 1 ID = 1 SUM)

Получится примерно такая сводная таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]